# Reformatting a method options hash

Tags: ruby

I am writing an API wrapper and the endpoint takes dates in a very specific format.

The user of the API can pass in the parameters in whatever format they prefer, but regardless of what they pass in, I want to be able to clean up their input prior to submitting their query.

My question centers around the best way to update the options hash in place, and I have thought of a few possible ways to implement.

1. A helper method inside the class so you can overwrite `options = reformat_hash(options)`
2. A singleton on that specific variable

   ```ruby
   def options.clean_up!
     # see internals below
   end
   ```
3. Or open up `Hash` and do the cleaning from the class

   ```ruby
   class Hash
     def clean_hash!
       self.each { |key, value|
         if value.is_a? Date
           self[key] = value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
         else
           self[key] = value.to_s
         end
       }
     end
   end
   ```

   so that I can just call it on whatever the variable may be named like:

   ```ruby
   def api_request(options={})
     options.clean_hash!
     # the options variable is now clean and I can pass it to the api
     HHTParty.get(path, :query => options).parsed_response
   end
   ```

Is there a best practice for modifying or formatting hashes after they're passed into a method?

I feel like #3 is the neatest, but should I be worried about opening up `Hash` to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, while it may look nice, the method clean_hash is not general enough to be valid across all Hashes. So adding a method such as clean_hash to all Hashes would only serve to increase the coupling which is bad. A second problem is that you are mutating your method argument which is almost never advisable.

The  solution is to define the `clean` method outside, perhaps as a part of your internal API object and call `HHTParty.get(path, :query => clean(options)).parsed_response`.

I would also define the clean method this way

```
def clean(opt)
  Hash[opt.collect{|k,v| [k,v.is_a? Date : v.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S'):v.to_s ]}]
end
```

Comment: thanks blufox. I think I will include it in the get query like that, although I may use a different enumerable based on this https://gist.github.com/3158814.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than extend the hash class with something that "isn't general enough to be valid across all classes" (blufox: well said), make a subclass of `Hash` named `CleanHash`.

I added `|| value.is_a?(Time)` so you could format `Time` in addition to `Date`.

```
class CleanHash < Hash
  def self.[](opts)
    super(opts).clean!
  end

  def []=(key,value)
    super(key,clean(value))
  end

  def clean(value)
    if value.is_a?(Date) || value.is_a?(Time)
      value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    else
      value.to_s
    end
  end

  def clean!
    self.each { |key, value|
      self[key] = value # don't clean(value) or it will clean twice
    }
  end
end
```

Examples below.

```
# example 1
h = CleanHash[:s=>"x",:n=>9,:d=>Date.today,:t=>Time.now]
# => {:s=>"x", :t=>"2012-07-20 09:21:18", :d=>"2012-07-20 00:00:00", :n=>"9"}
h[:d2] = Date.yesterday
# => {:d2=>"2012-07-19 00:00:00", :s=>"x", :t=>"2012-07-20 09:21:18", :d=>"2012-07-20 00:00:00", :n=>"9"}

# example 2
def api_request(options={})
  clean_options = CleanHash[options]
  # the options variable is now clean and I can pass it to the api
  HHTParty.get(path, :query => clean_options).parsed_response
end
```

It's still a `Hash` so you can pass it around as if it were a `Hash`.

```
h = CleanHash[:foo=>Date.today]
#=> {:foo=>"2012-07-20 00:00:00"}
h.class
#=> CleanHash
h.is_a?(Hash)
#=> true
```